# How can I send post request with null datas JSON in Robot Framework?

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I'm using Robot framework's RequestsKeywords to test a service. And there is a test case to send null datas to the service.
I want to send something with nulls like this as a request body:

```
data={
    id: "some-id", 
    name: null,
    address: null,
    tell_no: null
}
```

As in the document of Post Request, the data needs to be send a dictionary of key-value pairs.
https://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/

But how can I set my key-value pair with this null? I tried to do the $None as below:

```
${request_data}=    Create Dictionary
Set To Dictionary    ${request_data}    name=$None
```

But it just becomes a '$None' string instead in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for none is incorrect, it should be ${None}, if that doesn't work I would try ${EMPTY}.

Finally if both of the above aren't looking like the right answer, I would create an empty JSON file in your test data and simply point to its file location as the data.

Let us know which method works for you.